# Why this reverse script written in c# isn't working?

Tags: c#, string, reverse

I make this c# code with ubuntu.

```
///Uses swap method to reverse; need to traverse only half of the array.
public static stringReverseString2(string str)
{
   char[] chars = str.ToCharArray();
   for (int i =0, j = str.Length - 1; i < j; i++, j--)
   {
    char c = chars[i];
    chars[i] = chars[j];
    chars[j] = c;
   }
   return new string(chars);
}
```

But when I compile it I get this output

```
c++1.c:2:1: error: expected unqualified-id before ‘public’
public static stringReverseString2(string str)
^
```

How can I resolve it?

Sorry, but I'm new in c#

Comment: I tried your code and it reverses the entire string, considering that we have a string "123456789" what would be your desired output?

Comment: The error message says there something unexpected before the keyword `public` and you posted just the method starting with the keyword `public`. It's quite obvious that you're missing the only relevant part of the code in your question.

Comment: BTW are you sure you're not trying to compile the C# code with the C++ compiler (just an idea when I see `c++` in the error message)?

Comment: You can vastly simplify your reverse method to `return new string(str.Reverse().ToArray());`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

your method is lacking a return value

after `public static` you need to specify the type that you are returning:`string`

```
public static string stringReverseString2(string str)
```

or you could just add a space in the name

```
public static string ReverseString2(string str)
```

Answer (score 0):

Change your method to look like this:

```
 public static string StringReverseString2(string str)
{
    char[] chars = str.ToCharArray();
    for (int i = 0, j = str.Length - 1; i < j; i++, j--)
    {
        char c = chars[i];
        chars[i] = chars[j];
        chars[j] = c;
    }
    return new string(chars);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

you are doing an in-place string reversal , so why create a new string

use string builder instead, and add a return type to you method signature

```
public static StringBuilder  ReverseString2(StringBuilder str)
{
   for (int i =0, j = str.Length - 1; i < j; i++, j--)
   {
    var c = str[i];
    str[i] = str[j];
    str[j] = c;
   }
   return str;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you have deleted space by mistake from `public static string ReverseString2(string str)`.

You can do like this too.

```
public static string ReverseString2(string str)
{
    char[] chars = str.ToCharArray();
    Array.Reverse(chars);
    //for (int i = 0, j = str.Length - 1; i < j; i++, j--)
    //{
    //    char c = chars[i];
    //    chars[i] = chars[j];
    //    chars[j] = c;
    //}
    return new string(chars);
}
```